# Testing metric in middleware C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-telemetry

I need to test a middleware class that is used for recording metrics using opentelemetry. Some code in my unit test class:

```
    var exportedItems = new List<Metric>();
    var meterProv = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryExporter(exportedItems)
    .Build();

    IServiceCollection svcCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    svcCollection.AddSingleton<MeterProvider>(meterProv);
    RequestDelegate mockNextMiddleware = (httpContext) =>
    {
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    httpContext.RequestServices = svcCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var metricMiddleWare = new MetricMiddleware(mockNextMiddleware);

    //act
    await metricMiddleWare.InvokeAsync(httpContext);
```

I'm able to run and step into the middleware class, but exportedItems is never populated with any data. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and is this even possible?

Our app is .Net 6.0

exportedItems would have the metric values in it to check in the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly dispose `meterProv` to force the exporter to write metrics. Just add this line after invoking the middleware:

```
meterProv.Dispose()
```